# VBA code search and format text in word document - infinite loop

Tags: vba, loops, search

I have written the below code to search through a word document to select text between to words (i.e. from "Hide Note" to "Hide Note").  Once the text is selected it is then shaded.  I want the code to loop through the whole document once, but I seem to have created an infinite loop.  Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Thank you

---

```
`Sub SearchShade()

'Start of doc
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

'start of loop
Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Sel") = _
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc")

'Search
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
.Text = "Hide Note"
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindStop
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.Execute
End With

'Select down to next Hide Note
Selection.Extend
With Selection.Find
.Text = "Hide Note"
.Forward = True
.Execute
Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
End With

'Move down one para
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1

'Loop to end of document
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do until Selection.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc")
```

Comment: If my answer fixed your issue, could you mark it as the answer with the green checkmark. Thanks